# How to get column name for max date in a very large table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, max

I have a table that has 38 columns that are all datetime data type. 
I want to query the column name that has the max date in each row.

I have figured out how to determine the max date of each row, but I'm not sure how to query which column it came from.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MaxDates') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #MaxDates

SELECT 
   [ColumnOne], 
  Max( StartDate) as MaxEffDate

Into #MaxDates

FROM dbo.DatabaseName 

group by [ColumnOne]

Select a.[ColumnOne], StartDate,
 (SELECT MAX(LastUpdateDate)
      FROM (VALUES   
                 (case when (ColumnTwo) < '9999-12-31' then (ColumnTwo) else '1900-01-01' end)
                ) AS UpdateDate(LastUpdateDate) 
  ) AS LastUpdateDate
From dbo.DatabaseName  a
inner join #MaxDates
on a.[ColumnOne] =#MaxDates.[ColumnOne] and a.StartDate = #MaxDates.MaxEffDate
order by a.[ColumnOne] asc
```

I expect the following result-

```
ColumnOne, StartDate, LastUpdateDate, LastUpdateDateColumnName
```

Comment: It's not really clear to me how the text of the question relates to it's code and the desired output. Please read the first paragraph of the [Sql-Server tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you almost got it with your current query. You can make use of the `VALUE` or even `CROSS APPLY` to find the column with the max date

```
select  t.[ColumnOne], t.StartDate, d.LastUpdateDate, d.LastUpdateDateColumnName
from    dbo.DatabaseName t
        cross apply
        (
            select  top 1 LastUpdateDate, LastUpdateDateColumnName
            from    
            (   
                values 
                (Date1, 'Date1'),
                (Date2, 'Date2'),
                (Date3, 'Date3')
                ....
            ) as d (LastUpdateDate, LastUpdateDateColumnName)
            order by LastUpdateDate desc
        ) d
```